# VS2012 - How to Enable / Re-Enable Method List?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I used to be able to see the Method List below. But it seems that it's gone now and I have no idea how to re-enable it. Any help is appreciated :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this but I'm not sure if this will solve your problem.

Tools>Import and Export settings, and select Reset all settings

Comment: Thanks! But if possible I don't want to reset my other settings :)

Comment: i am really sorry, i dont know how to enable/disable only the method listing in VS. Whenever i run into problem is VS i reset everything and get back the factory defaults.

Comment: no worries. I will try your solution if no one can solve this. I have given you a vote up.

Comment: and ya let us know if it did solve your problem. ALL THE BEST.